# How to use .replace() function for replace "NULL"?

Tags: regex, replace

I need to use the `.replace()` function to replace `abc123="NULL"` with `abc123=NULL` but only when NULL is the only word between the quotation marks, otherwise, leave it as it is.

Struggling to find the correct combination of escpaped characters to make this work.

Note: there are no quotation marks at the beginning or end of this data value i.e. it is not `abc123="NULL"` that I am working with. It is explicitly `abc123="NULL"`

Can any one manage this?

Edit: I'm using a privately written development environment that builds using Java.

Edit: If I could it would look like this x.replace(="NULL", =NULL) BUT I need to escape the = and quotation marks. Baring in mind I can only do this replacement if the word is NULL and is not any other word.

Comment: You didn't specify the language in which you are working.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly: You want to set `abc123` to `NULL` if the value of `abc123` is `"NULL"`?

Comment: No I want to remove the quotation marks from the "NULL" part only when NULL is the word between the quotation marks.

Comment: So search all of: abc123="NULL". If "NULL" is found, replace "NULL" with NULL instead. But when searcing only remove the quotation marks if what is encapsulated between the quotation marks is the word NULL and not any other word.

Comment: When you print abc123 to console does it show "NULL". I doubt that...

Comment: It's important to treat abc123="NULL" as a string in it's own right here.

Comment: If I could it would look like this x.replace(="NULL", =NULL) BUT I need to escape the = and quotation marks. Baring in mind I can only do this replacement if the word is NULL and is not any other word.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. What's the surrounding code like? You're very likely trying to operate on something from a #toString that could easily be avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure to well understand but, is that what you want:

```js
var x = 'abc="NULL"';
x = x.replace('="NULL"', '=NULL');
console.log(x);
```

Comment: This is fine but it specificcally needs to replace '="NULL"' with '=NULL'. Can you alter the above to do so?

Comment: That did it, sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @NorthDave:No problems, glad it helps.